# Windows 10 booting takes forever (stuck at "Gigabyte™ – Insist on Ultra Durable" screen)

Tags: windows-10, boot, 64-bit, amd-ryzen

My Windows 10 takes forever to boot. 
It sticks here about 10 minutes before able to enter Windows.

[image: the "Gigabyte™ – Insist on Ultra Durable" screen, where it hangs]

#### Device specifications

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Device name | DESKTOP-G6SH72U |
| Processor | AMD Ryzen 3 PRO 4350G with Radeon Graphics 3.80 GHz |
| Installed RAM | 8,00 GB (7,41 GB usable) |
| Device ID | 773063F0-A828-491E-96C9-F24696BFE0D5 |
| Product ID | 00331-10000-00001-AA179 |
| System type | 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor |
| Pen and touch | No pen or touch input is available for this device |

<sup>Device specifications as [an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohnJq.png).</sup>

I am not sure what info should I put here to help you to solve my problem. Just ask me if you need more info.

Comment: Did you install Windows to a HDD or SSD?  Youl should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Yes; Except you have replied to my comment with a comment instead of editing your question. Which is the reason I reminded you that you should [edit] your question instead of providing information like that in a comment. Which know has to be flagged as no longer being necessary